# How to use HistoryLocation in react router?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

i am trying to use routes with history location because i dont want to use # inside my url's,i want to work with normal ones, i have been trying everything and every time i am getting the same error "Cannot GET /loginpro". i don't understand how the locations works, this is my code

```js
'use strict';
var React = require('react');
var Router = require('react-router'); // or var Router = ReactRouter; in browsers
var DefaultRoute = Router.DefaultRoute;
var Route = Router.Route;
var Cliente = require('./FormClientRegister');
var Login = require('./LoginProgresar');
var Contract = require('./FormContractRegister');

var routes =(<Route name="loginpro" path="/loginpro" handler={Login}/>);

Router.run(routes,Router.HistoryLocation,function (Handler) {
    React.render(<Handler />, document.getElementById('content'));
});
```

I am using react js 0.13.3 with webpack,grunt js,karma,jshintrc ,chrome as browser and i build the project with yeoman's react js generator

i am running my app in localhost like this:
http://localhost:8000/loginpro

Comment: Hey, welcome to Stack Overflow! In order for us to help you, it'd be great if you could provide some details about how your project is set up.

Comment: i already put more details in the question !

Comment: How are you serving your app? Did you implement a catchall route?

Comment: Yes i already try it but didn't work, i am serving the app with webpack and grunt.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're using the webpack dev server, you need to configure it to serve up your app for any URL that's requested, not just for `/`.

According to the [react-hot-loader troubleshooting docs](https://github.com/gaearon/react-hot-loader/blob/master/docs/Troubleshooting.md#i-can-access-my-single-page-app-spa-only-via--on-refresh), this should just be a case of adding `historyApiFallback: true` to the dev server config.

[This react-router issue](https://github.com/rackt/react-router/issues/676) has more discussion around this, including different configurations people have used.

Comment: I got it ,you are right , now it's working,thank you so much! .Sorry for for my poor knowledge about webpack , it's my first time using it